# getting error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, pyopenssl

In Python, I am trying to print the result which contains data in JSON format.

code I am using is generating output only when I run the program 1st time, but if I try to run it 2nd time it is generating SSL Error I have installed all the required packages.

**JSON_URL**:
[image]

**Error**:

raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='serpapi.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?api_key=SecretApiKey&device=desktop&engine=home_depot&q=chair&output=json&source=python (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

```
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "api_key": "SecretApiKey",
    "device": "desktop",
    "engine": "home_depot",
    "q": "chair"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
print(results)
```

Comment: Could you tell on which OS you're running? macOS, Linux, Windows? If you're on Linux based terminal, then try `pip install certifi`, after that, run this command `bash /Applications/Python*/Install\ Certificates.command`

Comment: @DmitriyZub I am using Windows. What can I do for windows?

Comment: could you try to run `pip install --upgrade pip` and then `pip install -U requests[security]` which will install `certifi` that possibly fix your problem. Let me know if it's helped.

Comment: @DmitriyZub still getting same error of:                                                                     raise SSLError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='serpapi.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /search?api_key=SecretApiKey&device=desktop&engine=home_depot&q=chair&output=json&source=python (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))